# estou tento problemas com um contador em javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

eu estou tentado criar um jogo clicker com html e javascript, mas eu estou tendo problemas com a implementação de um "contador" de moedas

```
var moedasTotal = 0;
var valorMoeda = 1;
var MoedasPsec = 1;

var MPScounter = document.getElementById("counter-mps");
var btnMoeda = document.getElementById("btnMoeda");
var Contador = document.getElementById("Contador");

btnMoeda.innerText = (" + " + valorMoeda);

// function botão moedas 

btnMoeda.addEventListener("click", () => {
    moedasTotal += valorMoeda;
    Contador.innerHTML = moedasTotal;
})

Contador.addEventListener("change")

// contador de moedas por segundo 

setInterval(() => {
    MoedasPsec += moedasTotal;
}, 1000);
```

a variável `moedasTotal` é a quantidade de moedas totais que você, tem e a variável `moedasPsec` se refere a quantidade de moedas que você deve ganhar por segundo.

1. eu queria que a cada 1 segundo, o valor da variável `moedasPsec` fosse adicionado a `moedasTotal`, mas o código não funciona. como posso solucionar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve inverter a lógica da função dentro do `setInterval`, da maneira como está fazendo, sua lógica está invertida.

[Documentação (operadores de atribuição)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operador_atribuicao)

A variável que vem a esquerda do operador `+=` deve ser a variável que terá o novo valor, e a variável a esquerda é o que será somado para calvular o novo valor, ou seja:

`x += y` significa `x = x + y`

Transformando isso na sua lógica é assim:

`MoedasPsec += moedasTotal` significa `MoedasPsec = MoedasPsec + moedasTotal`

Dito isso, deve-se inverter a lógica da sua soma para que fique assim:

`moedasTotal += MoedasPsec` significa `moedasTotal = moedasTotal + MoedasPsec`